# Android: switch statement wasn't working two months ago, but doesn't make trouble now

Tags: android

Couple of months ago, in my android code, whenever I used a switch statement, I had a strange error (unfortunately I dont remember what it was) and I read on the internet that I should change it to if else if statement, because there was some general problem with the way android handled those

A few days ago I was experimenting and I implemented a switch statement and didn't have any trouble.

Can I alter my if else if statements to switch statements now? Is someone familiar with what the problem was?

**EDIT**: Here is one of the source that explained the problem 
http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields

note the line that says:

*The solution for this is simple: Convert the switch statement into an if-else statement.*

Comment: I never had any trouble with switch statements in Android code. Can you cite the source that claimed that this was "some general problem"?

Comment: I will do my best to find out

Comment: and please also share the code you were having problems with..

Comment: I found the source and I've added it to my question. unfortunately, I dont remember which piece of my code was giving me trouble

Comment: `switch` is little more than syntactic sugar for multiple `if-else` statements annyway.  That said, the case you have linked to is a very specific example where you are switching on resource IDs.  In general, there are no problems with switches in Android (actually, in the Java compiler which the ADT uses).  You should definitely use switches for readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 2):

switch in jdk 1.6 was only handling integers as most of other languages.

> In the new sdk 1.7 switch also handle String values. in some how it
>   uses the equals method inside the String class to handle comparison.